# Recursive GCD not returning expected results

Tags: python, recursion, greatest-common-divisor

This function in Python is to find the greatest common divisor of 2 integers recursively. But I was not able to get it to work as it should be in the test

```
def gcdRecur(a, b):
    if a > b:
        (a,b) = (b,a)
    if b%a == 0:
        #print("b%a == 0")
        print ("a is " + str(a))
        return a
    else:
        gcdRecur(b%a,b)



print("gcdRecur(45, 42) " + "should be 3, and we got " + str(gcdRecur(45, 42)))
print("gcdRecur(6, 12) " + "should be 6, and we got " + str(gcdRecur(6, 12)))
print("gcdRecur(12, 16) " + "should be 4, and we got " + str(gcdRecur(12, 16)))
print("gcdRecur(17, 12) " + "should be 1, and we got " + str(gcdRecur(17,12)))
```

Comment: missing a `return` in your `else` statement

Answer (score 1):

like my comment said. you are missing a `return` in your `else` statement.

```
else:
    return gcdRecur(b%a,b)
```

You need the return statement here because you need to chain the return from your recursive. Using `Sven Marnach`'s function which can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5537507/4099813

We can take the trace function Sven wrote and see what's going on and why you need the return statement. (we need to modify his function to accept multiple arguments:

```
def trace(f):
    indent = 0
    def g(*x):
        nonlocal indent
        print('|  ' * indent + '|--', f.__name__, x)
        indent += 1
        value = f(*x)
        print('|  ' * indent + '|--', 'return', repr(value))
        indent -= 1
        return value
    return g

def gcdRecur(a, b):
if a > b:
    (a,b) = (b,a)
if b%a == 0:
    return a
else:
    gcdRecur(b%a,b)

gcdRecur = trace(gcdRecur)

gcdRecur(45,42)
```

Which when ran, it gives us :

```
|-- gcdRecur (45, 42)
|  |-- gcdRecur (3, 45)
|  |  |-- return 3
|  |-- return None
```

Notice it's returning None because you didn't state it should return the value it finds in the next level of recursion?

Adding the `return` to the `else` statement will yield:

```
|-- gcdRecur (45, 42)
|  |-- gcdRecur (3, 45)
|  |  |-- return 3
|  |-- return 3
```

Comment: Yep, it works out great after adding the "return"! Thanks for the help!